# Central Directory corrupt when deploying from appveyor environment

Tags: deployment, appveyor

[image: Central Directory corrupt]

Hello, I have 2 environments, test and uat, after commiting my changes in github a new build started on our build agent appveyor. The build succeeded and I was able to deploy to the test environment. But when I try to deploy the same package in uat I get this error (first time I see this).

Does anyone know what is wrong with the deployment? I did a quick search on google all I could find about this error is when people try to create a zip file (which is not my case since the zip file already exists in the build agent server)

Thank you

Comment: Some time poor network will also lead to this error. Trying again helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out where the problem was. The disk on the uat machine had no space left. Releasing some space on uat made the deployment possible.

Would be nice to have a different message instead of corrupted directory.

Comment: Thank you for update. Right AppVeyor VM has a lot of software not everyone needs. For example removing msys64 will free more about 3Gb for you. For that you can add `rmdir /s /q c:\msys64` into ‘install’ stage.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but updating to the [latest version](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/agent/#installing-appveyor-deployment-agent) of the AppVeyor Deployment Agent fixed it for me.